# getUserMedia does not work with SSL certificates installed

Tags: ssl, https, modernizr, getusermedia

I'm using modernizr to detect if getusermedia is enabled, but it's giving me an error. The code is very simple:

```
if (Modernizr.getusermedia) {
    const mic = new p5.AudioIn();
    mic.start();
} else {
    console.log('getUserMedia() is not supported in your browser');
}
```

I installed https certificates with letsencrypt. In previous versions of the website it worked, but now it's giving me an error, even though visiting the website through the https protocol works fine.

the website is running on apache, virtualhost, digital ocean. It's currently live, I can message the url if necessary.

edit:
Let's elaborate on this, how can I find out what could be causing this error? I tried googling, but i'm not sure which keywords to look for except what I wrote here.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @jib that's the weird thing.. there's no error! You can check it at https://flowen.me if you check console, you see usermedia not supported, but the https protocol is working

Comment: I don't know this library at all, but typing `Modernizr.getusermedia` into the web console on your page yields `true`, so maybe you just need to wait for the page to load, e.g. using `window.onload`?

Comment: @jib Thanks fr the suggestion! Totally forgot about it. But it still made no sense. I received the console log that it's not supported, but still returns true. I removed modernizr and it works fine. I'm going to create an issue @ their github.